# How to know if WebBrowser is finished downloading the file? Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a code that will download a file using `WebBrowser.Navigate(DownloadLink)` and it works fine. But I want my application to automatically exit itself after the download is finished. And I don't know how to do it. So is there any way on how to know if `WebBrowser` is finished downloading?

Comment: Can you just monitor the file that you selected for download until it reaches the expected file size?

Comment: To download a file, you don't need to use `WebBrowserControl`. You can simply use [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`WebClient.DownloadFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebBrowser` component is a wrapper around Internet Explorer, which downloads asynchronously. Now we could come up with various hacks that would answer your question and maybe solve the problem, but I strongly suggest to use a different approach to download a file, at least if there's no other reason for you to keep WebBrowser in your application:

[WebClient.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) "This method blocks while downloading the resource".

```
Public Sub Download(address As String, localfile As String)
    Using client As New System.Net.WebClient()
        client.DownloadFile("some url", "local file path to save")
    End Using
End Sub
```

You also can use [`WebClient.DownloadFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx) which doesn't block UI.